# Arithmetic operation fails in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Basically I'm trying to check if there are any  200 http responses in the log, in last 3 line. but I'm getting the below error. Because of this the head command is failing..Please help

```
    LINES=`cat http_access.log |wc -l`
    for i in  $LINES $LINES-1 $LINES-2

do
        echo "VALUE $i"
        head -$i http_access.log | tail -1 > holy.txt
        temp=`cat holy.txt| awk '{print $9}'`

        if [[ $temp == 200 ]]
        then
        echo "line $i has 200 code at "
        cat holy.txt | awk '{print $4}'
        fi
done
```

Output:

> VALUE 18 
>   line 18 has 200 code at [21/Jan/2018:15:34:23
>   **VALUE 18-1** 
>   head: invalid trailing option -- - Try `head --help' for more information.

Comment: `$foo-1` expands to the contents of the variable `foo`, with the string `-1` concatenated to the end; it's a string operation, not an arithmetic operation, unless explicitly placed in an arithmetic context.

Comment: `temp=\`cat holy.txt| awk '{print $9}'\`` is better written as `temp=$(awk '{print $9}' holy.txt)`.  None of your uses of the external program `cat` are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$((...))` to perform arithmetic.

```
for i in $((LINES)) $((LINES-1)) $((LINES-2))
```

Without it, it's attempting to run the commands:

```
head -18 http_access.log
head -18-1 http_access.log
head -18-2 http_access.log
```

The latter two are errors.

A more flexible way to write the `for` loop would be using C-style syntax:

```
for ((i = LINES - 2; i <= LINES; ++i)); do
    ...
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it did help. 

can't I user in the below format ?


for i in {$((LINES))..$((LINES-10))}

Answer (score 1):

You got the *why* from [JohnKugelman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48373114/6176817), I will just propose a simplified code that might work for you:

```
while read -ra fields; do
    [[ ${fields[9]} = 200 ]] && echo "Line ${fields[0]} has 200 code: ${fields[4]}"
done < <(cat -n http_access.log | tail -n 3 | tac)
```

- `cat -n`: Numbers lines of the file
- `tail -n 3`: Prints 3 last lines. You can just change this number for more lines
- `tac`: Prints the lines outputted by `tail` in reversed order
- `read -ra fields`: Reads the fields into an array `$fields`
- `${fields[0]}`: The line number
- `${fields[num_of_field]}`: Individual fields

---

You can also use `wc` instead of numbering using `cat -n`. For larger inputs, this will be slightly faster:

```
lines=$(wc -l < http_access.log)
while read -ra fields; do
    [[ ${fields[8]} = 200 ]] && echo "Line $lines has 200 code: ${fields[3]}"
    ((lines--))
done < <(tail -n 3 http_access.log | tac)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This scrips checks from top 16 to 18th line but I need this scrip to check from the bottom

Comment: @Iqbalhonnur fixed

Comment: `cat -n http_access.log | tail -n 3`: this is to save `wc -l` and counting `((line--))`

Comment: @BachLien I used `nl` in the first snippet (changed it to `cat -n` because that is indeed better). However, considering **large** inputs, `cat -n` is slower than `wc`, so using `wc` + counting will be slightly faster.

Comment: @BachLien Testing on 3M lines, `cat -n` took about 0.18s, whereas `wc -l` approach took around 0.04s. The difference is negligible even when comparing more than 3 lines. Tried 10,000 lines, 0.6s for `cat -n`, 0.35 for `wc -l`. For comparing even more lines, I don't think looping with `bash` is the right approach anyway :)